# Split or join two use cases that are similar in Clean Architecture

Tags: use-case, clean-architecture

In my working project I have a `CustomerRegisterUseCase`, that has following steps:

- validate email is already in use;
- hash password;
- save customer in temporary table(tranfered to customer table after email validation);
- generate email validation code;
- send email validation;

But other part of company wanna create a customer directly, without email validation, following this steps

- validate email is already in use;
- hash password;
- save in customer table;

The question is: Do I split in two use cases or do I use same use case, but passing a `activeEmailValidation` flag?

Comment: First impression: "other part of company" implies different users, so I'd default to separate user stories, so you don't tie to different users to one story. But YMMV.

Comment: humm, i dont know much about user stories development, but i am working in  system with inconsistences :( , where sometimes the data existis in one repository and does not exist in other, so this "other part of company" refers to syncronize data beetween sistems( yeah i know, this sucks), so i trying to "clean the house"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, no one-fit-all solution or rule of thumb. Only tradeoffs. We can't tell you what to do, because the final solution will depend on factors not strictly related to this use case. It's going to be influenced by the context and the conditions you work in too.

> i am working in system with inconsistences :( , where sometimes the data exists in one repository and does not exist in other, so this "other part of company" refers to synchronize data between systems

It sounds like a good reason to separate both use cases, it makes for a more flexible and resilient solution (tolerant to change).

From my point of view (developer), it compartmentalises the complexity and the uncertainty generated by the "inconsistencies". It breaks a big problem into smaller ones. That's, definitively, a smart way to build confidence and manage the uncertainty of your current context.

From the perspective of the source code, it will result in code easier to read, understand, test and change too. It will conform to the S & O of SOLID principles, both quite present in C.A. Moreover, it's going to be aligned with the C.A philosophy of adding new business capabilities by adding new use cases instead of messing with the existing ones (which is contrary to the Open-Close principle).

Regarding *`"do I use same use case, but passing a activeEmailValidation flag?"`*.

In most cases, forking code to add new business capabilities is a bad strategy. Over time, code becomes unmanageable and harder to maintain (aka, change). This solution is not time-proof.

Some might argue that is KISS, but it's not. It's only a shortcut to hell. Simplicity is dictated by the architecture and C.A makes creating a new use case the easier, more reasonable and expected thing to do.